# Rewrite OR add custom tab to the sales order view in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, sales

I want to add custom tab to sales order view form. I tried the following code, but nothing happend. ([Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084786/how-do-i-add-a-tab-to-the-sale-order-admin-page), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789216/custom-tab-on-sales-order-view)).

My layout module.xml code is

```
 <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
            <action method="addTab"><name>my_tab</name><block>mymodule/Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Tabs</block></action>
        </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

And my block class is :

```
class Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Tabs  extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Abstract
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        Mage::Log("Fraud created");
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve order model instance
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return Mage::registry('current_order');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve source model instance
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
     */
    public function getSource()
    {
        return $this->getOrder();
    }


    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return Mage::helper('sales')->__('Fraud Detection');
    }

    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return Mage::helper('sales')->__('Fraud Detection');
    }

    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any error in the above code ? thanks in advance

Comment: so how to add form in newly created tab? if someone can provide code that will be great. because I am confuse with form creation with controller.php or block.php or xml..... I ll really appreciate your help..
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

Create: `app/code/local/MagePal/OrderFraudDetectionTab/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MagePal_OrderFraudDetectionTab>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </MagePal_OrderFraudDetectionTab>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <orderfrauddetectiontab>
                <class>MagePal_OrderFraudDetectionTab_Block</class>
            </orderfrauddetectiontab>
        </blocks>
    </global>       
    <adminhtml>
       <layout>
            <updates>
                <orderfrauddetectiontab>
                    <file>magpal_orderfrauddetectiontab.xml</file>
                </orderfrauddetectiontab>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Create: `app/code/local/MagePal/OrderFraudDetectionTab/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Tab/FraudDetection.php`

```
<?php
class MagePal_OrderFraudDetectionTab_Block_Adminhtml_Order_View_Tab_FraudDetection
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{    
    //change _constuct to _construct()
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('magpal/orderfrauddetectiontab/order/view/tab/frauddetection.phtml');
    }

    public function getTabLabel() {
        return $this->__('Fraud Detection');
    }

    public function getTabTitle() {
        return $this->__('Fraud Detection');
    }

    public function canShowTab() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden() {
        return false;
    }

    public function getOrder(){
        return Mage::registry('current_order');
    }
} 
?>
```

Create:  `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/magpal/orderfrauddetectiontab/order/view/tab/frauddetection.phtml`

```
<?php echo 'add your html/php code here'; ?>
```

Create: `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/magpal_orderfrauddetectiontab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>order_view_tab_orderfrauddetectiontab</name>
                 <block>orderfrauddetectiontab/adminhtml_order_view_tab_frauddetection</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
</layout>
```

Create: `app/etc/modules/MagePal_OrderFraudDetectionTab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <modules>
        <MagePal_OrderFraudDetectionTab>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MagePal_OrderFraudDetectionTab>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.what would be the way if i want to load grid not phtml in costructor ?

Comment: The way i normal do this is to add `echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('orderfrauddetectiontab/adminhtml_frauddetection_edit_tab_form')->toHtml();' to my phtml

Comment: typo in class MagePal_OrderFraudDetectionTab_Block_Adminhtml_Order_View_Tab_FraudDetection constructor, __construct and scope should be public.
`code`
public function __construct()
{

Comment: This solution is not working for me. No new tab is showing in Sales >> Order section